# Poker Strategy for all ins

Tags: probability

If an opponent goes all in pre-flop and I have 8 8 and everybody else has folded, what are the respective odds on either player winning the hand?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what kinds of hands your opponent would go all-in with.  If it's a tournament and he's short stacked in late position, he might have many types of hands. If it's a cash game or early in a tournament and he's got a relatively large stack, his range of hands is likely a lot tighter. Of course, if you know this opponent and his tendencies, you might be able to narrow it down a little more.

You can estimate your odds of winning against a range of hands with an equity calculator such as PokerStove.

1. Against a random hand, your odds of winning are about 69%.
2. Against the top 50% of hands, your odds are about 60%. (Your opponent could have 33+,A2s+,K2s+,Q2s+,J4s+,T6s+,96s+,86s+,76s,65s,A2o+,K5o+,Q7o+,J7o+,T8o+,98o)
3. Against the top 30%, your odds are about 55%. (55+,A2s+,K5s+,Q7s+,J8s+,T8s+,98s,A7o+,A5o,K9o+,Q9o+,J9o+,T9o)
4. Against the top 20%, your odds are about 51%. (66+,A4s+,K8s+,Q9s+,J9s+,T9s,A9o+,KTo+,QTo+,JTo)
5. Against the top 10%, your odds are about 44%. (88+,A9s+,KTs+,QTs+,AJo+,KQo)
6. Against the top 5%, your odds are about 34%. (99+,AJs+,KQs,AKo)

So, this really becomes an exercise in estimating your opponent's hand range here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a bluff you are facing:

- two over cards
  this is what you are hoping for
  you are pretty close to a coin flip 1:1
  QJ suited has a more ways to beat you so you are very close to 1:1
  not suited not connected you are like a 57:42 favorite
  but A9o is not a likely push
  what 88 has going for it is that it is block on Q high straight or lower
- over pair
  this is what you fear
  you are a 4.5:1 dog
  you are dog to AA - 99
  a lot of players will shove with AA - JJ

If you are less than 10 BB then you kind of need to gamble. 
Less than 20 BB and you have blinds coming up might be time to gamble

If you have them covered and they are short stacked then they could be pushing with a wider range; you and can afford to lose; so I would gamble.

Clearly, 88 is hand that would rather get in cheap and is not afraid of multiple opponents. You are 8:1 for flopping a set and that is a hand that would likely hold up.

TT is a better hand in that spot.  As you have blocks on a Ace high straight.  A loose player *could* play ATs KTs that you dominate 2:1.  JJ is a hand is a hand I would typically call with unless they are tight.

[starting hands odds](http://www.toppoker.org/poker-hands/starting-hand-odds-dm.html)

If it is a bluff or semi bluff then 88 stands up good
It is a pair and a block on a wide range of straights
If you think they are coming in light then a good hand to make a stand
If you are in the blinds and the raise came from the CO then call

- Say they are semi bluffing 67 suited:
  You are 4:1
- Even a semi bluff with A little suited:
  You are 2:1
- On an outright bluff of 2 under:
  You are 4.5:1